# making a board terminal with blessed library in python

Tags: python

I'm making a game with blessed library in python, I didn't manage to get it to work. I want to make a board of 20×20.

I managed to do it with colored in this way:

```
import colored

nb_rows = 20
nb_cols = 20

to_display = ''
for row_id in range(nb_rows):
    for col_id in range(nb_cols):
            if (row_id + col_id) % 2 == 0:
                to_display += colored.bg('yellow') + colored.fg('red')
            else:
                to_display += colored.bg('green') + colored.fg('blue')
                
            to_display += '--' + colored.attr('reset')
    
    to_display += '\n'
    
print(to_display)
```

I want to do the same, but in blessed

Any help, thanks

Comment: What have you tried with blessed? Please post your code.

Comment: @kwsp I didn't manage to make columns in blessed, just a normal terminal with the import command `from blessed import Terminal`